# Error when write spark dataframe from Databricks into Azure Synapse

Tags: apache-spark, jdbc, pyspark, databricks, azure-synapse

I am trying to write the spark dataframe into Azure Syanpse database.

My code:

```
try:
  re_spdf.write \
    .format("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.spark") \
    .mode("append") \
    .option("url", url) \
    .option("dbtable", table_name) \
    .option("user", username) \
    .option("password", password) \
    .option("encrypt", 'True') \
    .option("trustServerCertificate", 'false') \
    .option("hostNameInCertificate", '*.database.windows.net') \
    .option("mssqlIsolationLevel", "READ_UNCOMMITTED") \
    .option('driver', 'com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver')\
    .save()
except ValueError as error :
    print("Connector write failed", error)
```

Error message:

```
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: 
Task 1 in stage 29.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: 
Lost task 1.3 in stage 29.0 (TID 885, 10.139.64.8, executor 0):
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException:
PdwManagedToNativeInteropException ErrorNumber: 46724, MajorCode: 467, 
MinorCode: 24, Severity: 20, State: 2, Exception of type 
&#39;Microsoft.SqlServer.DataWarehouse.Tds.PdwManagedToNativeInteropException&#39; was thrown.
```

Even I googled this error message. I didnt get any useful solution.

Update: My working environment is Databricks pyspark notebook.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is some column length limitation in the synapse DB table. It will allow only 4000 characters.

so When I use the `com.databricks.spark.sqldw` since it uses `Polybase` as the connector, I need to change the length of the column in DB table as well.
reference:https://forums.databricks.com/questions/21032/databricks-throwing-error-sql-dw-failed-to-execute.html

code:

```
df.write \
  .format("com.databricks.spark.sqldw") \
  .mode("append") \
  .option("url", url) \
  .option("user", username) \
  .option("password", password) \
  .option("maxStrLength", "4000" ) \
  .option("tempDir", "tempdirdetails") \
  .option("forwardSparkAzureStorageCredentials", "true") \
  .option("mssqlIsolationLevel", "READ_UNCOMMITTED") \
  .option("dbTable", table_name) \
  .save()
```

Answer (score 1):

[Azure databricks documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/data/data-sources/azure/synapse-analytics#python-2) says format `com.databricks.spark.sqldw` to read/write data from/to data from an Azure Synapse table.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I already tried this parameter which required a temp directory to store the data in between. I am trying without using a temp storage.

Comment: At the end, I used the tempdir option. thanks for the format suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Synapse, why not Synapse notebooks and then writing the dataframe is as easy as calling `synapsesql`, eg

```
%%spark
df.write.synapsesql("yourPool.dbo.someXMLTable_processed", Constants.INTERNAL)
```

You would save yourself some trouble and performance should be good as it's parallelised.  This is the main article:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/spark/synapse-spark-sql-pool-import-export

Comment: Thanks for the new direction. my all preprocessing is running on databricks.. so my running platform would be databricks only..